# Find the missing entity:

Tags: logical-deduction

Ao, Eo, Io, _ ? _, Uo

What is the missing entity. Provide the reasoning to back up your answer.

I have considered Oo already but that doesn't seem to be the required solution. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Where is this puzzle from? If *you* don't know the answer, I suspect it will be little more than a mind-reading exercise with this little information.

Comment: Fond or find, which one

Comment: @Deusovi Apparently it's a BlackRock Software Engineering interview question.

Comment: @Duck: Fill the blank: Fand, fend, find, ____, fund.

Comment: fond? What do you mean

Comment: It seems to have something to do with Keplerian elements, orbits, and other such astronomy things.

Comment: Who says Oo is not the required solution?

Answer (score 2):

> Ao, Eo, Io, Mo, Qo, Uo

Where:

> The first _ is "Mo", the ? is "," and the second _ is "Qo"

Because:

> A is 1, E is 5, I is 9 and U is 21. "The Hilbert numbers or S-numbers are numbers of the form 4n + 1" M is 13 and Q is 17, completing the sequence

Answer (score 0):

Is this an interview or test question?

If so, perhaps it's:

> Qo or theta-o

Ao, Eo and Io are all

> astronomical variables for orbit equations and crazy three-body problem math...